# cut vertices of connected and non connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $v$ is a cut-vertex of a connected graph $G$, then $v$ is NOT a cut vertex of $G'$.

I know that a vertex $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$ IFF there exists vertices $u$ and $w$ $(u,w \not=v)$ such that $v$ is on every $u-w$ path of $G$.

I also know that the complement $G'$ of a graph $G$ is a graph with vertex set $V(G)$ such that two vertices are adjacent in $G'$ IFF they are NOT adjacent in $G$.

So is it correct to conclude that there are no $u-w$ paths in $G'$ on which $v$ is found?

I don't know how to set up this proof

Answer (score 2):

By definition of a cut vertex, $G \setminus \{v\}$ has more components than $G$.  Let $X$ be one of these components.  Let $Y$ be $G \setminus \{v\} \setminus X$.  This is illustrated below:

[image]

Since $X$ is a connected component of $G \setminus \{v\}$, there are no edges from $X$ to any vertex in $Y$ (otherwise this vertex would also be in $X$).  Hence, in $G'$, every vertex of $X$ is connected to every vertex in $Y$.  We illustrate this subgraph of $G'$ below:

[image]

Both $X$ and $Y$ exist and are non-empty (since $v$ is a cut vertex).  We see that $G' \setminus \{v\}$ has one component (any pair of vertices is connected via a path of the form $x_i y_j$ or $x_i y_1 x_j$ or $y_i x_1 y_j$).

If $v$ were a cut vertex of $G'$, then $G' \setminus \{v\}$ would have more components than $G'$ (which has at least one component, since it contains the vertex $v$), but $G' \setminus \{v\}$ has only one component, giving a contradiction.  Hence $v$ is not a cut vertex of $G'$.

Comment: I don't know how to show those properties of $G'$ can you please show me how?

Comment: not complete argument.What about if they are in the same component ?